# How to purge directory with puppet and keep the dot files

Tags: puppet

Is there a way to purge the folder and keep the dotfiles? I'd like to purge the /root.

Something like:

```
file { '/root':
  ensure => present,
  owner => 'root',
  group => 'root',
  mode => 0550,
  purge => true,
  recurse => true,
}

file { '/root/.*':
  ensure => present,
  owner => 'root',
  group => 'root',
}
```

Comment: Without knowing puppet, how about the [ignore tag](http://docs.puppetlabs.com/references/latest/type.html#file-attribute-ignore)?

Answer (score 1):

Either go for the `ignore` param as h2ooooooo correctly stated.

You may find it cleaner to not recurse and use the tidy type and its [matches](http://docs.puppetlabs.com/references/latest/type.html#tidy-attribute-matches) parameter instead.

```
tidy { "/root": recurse => 1, matches => '[a-zA-Z0-9_]*' }
```

Answer (score 1):

My final solution looks like this:

```
file { '/root':
  ensure => present,
  owner => 'root',
  group => 'root',
  mode => 0550,
  purge => true,
  recurse => true,
  force => true,
  ignore => ['.*',
    'bullx_yum_install.log',
    'install.log',
    'install.log.syslog'],
}
```